# Create a categorical variable from date data in R

Tags: r, date, categories

I have data that includes dates (dd/mm/yyyy) and am wanting to summarise the data by year. I'm sure that there is an easier way to do it but the route that I've taken is to try to create a new categorical variable using the "cut" function.

For example:

```
# create sample dataframe 
dates<-c("01/01/2013", "01/02/2013", "01/01/2014", "01/02/2014", "01/01/2015", "01/02/2015")
cases<-c(3,5,2,6,8,4)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(dates, cases))
df$dates <- as.Date(df$dates,"%d/%m/%Y")

# categorise by year 
df$year <- cut(df$dates, c(2013-01-01, 2013-12-31, 2014-12-31, 2015-12-31))
```

This gives an error:

```
invalid specification of 'breaks'
```

How do I tell R to cut at various "date" intervals? Is my approach to this all wrong? Still new to R (sorry about the basic question).

Greg

Comment: Your `breaks` argument is wrong. The input should either be strings (which might work), or date objects which can be easily constrcuted using strings (see answer of Leo P.).

Comment: Note that the cbind ensures that `cases` becomes a character and not a numeric.

Answer (score 1):

How should your output look like?

Your code works when you define your breaks with `as.Date`:

```
breaks <- as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2013-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2015-12-31"))

# categorise by year 
df$year <- cut(df$dates, breaks)

       dates cases       year
1 2013-01-01     3 2013-01-01
2 2013-02-01     5 2013-01-01
3 2014-01-01     2 2013-12-31
4 2014-02-01     6 2013-12-31
5 2015-01-01     8 2014-12-31
6 2015-02-01     4 2014-12-31
```

I'm guessing you want your variable `year` to look different, though? You can define `labels` when using `cut`:

```
# categorise by year 
df$year <- cut(df$dates, breaks, labels = c(2013, 2014, 2015))

       dates cases year
1 2013-01-01     3 2013
2 2013-02-01     5 2013
3 2014-01-01     2 2014
4 2014-02-01     6 2014
5 2015-01-01     8 2015
6 2015-02-01     4 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are just looking for the year, maybe this helps:

`df$year <- format(df$dates, format="%Y")`

```
       dates cases year
1 2013-01-01     3 2013
2 2013-02-01     5 2013
3 2014-01-01     2 2014
4 2014-02-01     6 2014
5 2015-01-01     8 2015
6 2015-02-01     4 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be using the `dplyr` package. Here is a simple example:

```
library(dplyr)

df_grouped <- df %>%
  mutate(
    dates = as_date(dates),
    cases = as.numeric(cases)) %>%
  group_by(year = year(dates)) %>%
  summarise(tot_cases = sum(cases))
```

In the `mutate` statement we convert the variables to a more suitable format, in `group_by` we select which variable is going to do the grouping and in `summarise` we create any new variables that we want.

`df_grouped` looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   year tot_cases
  <dbl>     <dbl>
1  2013         6
2  2014         6
3  2015         9
```

Comment: Note that the outcome of your solution is not correct. The `cases` column in `df` is a factor. Calling `as.numeric` on it will not create a correct number out of it, but give the underlying category ID of the factor level. You need to call `as.numeric(as.character())` to ensure the correct outcome. See my answer for the correct solution. In addition, you are missing 2015 in the output you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solutions based on `cut` are a bit overkill. You can use the `year` function from the `lubridate` package to extract the year from the date:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% mutate(year = year(dates))
#        dates cases year
# 1 2013-01-01     3 2013
# 2 2013-02-01     5 2013
# 3 2014-01-01     2 2014
# 4 2014-02-01     6 2014
# 5 2015-01-01     8 2015
# 6 2015-02-01     4 2015
```

`lubridate` is such an awesome package when it comes to dealing with time data.

After the `year` column is constructed you can apply all kinds of summaries. I use the `dplyr` style here:

```
# Note that as.numeric(as.character()) is needed as `cbind` forces `cases` to be a factor
df %>% mutate(year = year(dates), cases = as.numeric(as.character(cases))) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% summarise(tot_cases = sum(cases))
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#   year tot_cases
#   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1  2013         8
# 2  2014         8
# 3  2015        12
```

Note that `group_by` ensures that all operations after that are done per unique category mentioned there, in this case per year.